# Is this plot possible in R? As geom col or bar or something else

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to make something like this in R as shown in the image. I've tried facet wrap, geom_col/bar. However it doesn't seem possible without a lengthy code someone had posted a while ago on Rstudio community if I'm not wrong. Any ideas folks?[image]

Here is some sample data and code below:

```
149 Lab B          NNK [ng/g]  HKH 10448.00
14  Lab A         DBAA [ng/g]  HGT     0.00
642 Lab A        HCHO [mug/g]  SKH  8828.48
202 Lab B           Be [ng/g]  HMH    21.70
361 Lab B       Ch3CH [mug/g]  MGT     0.00
308 Lab B         NPYR [ng/g]  HPT   340.40
806 Lab A         NDMA [ng/g]  SPT    49.39
413 Lab A          NAP [ng/g]  MKH     0.00
526 Lab B           Hg [ng/g]  MMH     2.20
87  Lab A           Cd [ng/g]  HKH   273.00
80  Lab A         AFB1 [ng/g]  HKH     0.00
145 Lab B           Ni [ng/g]  HKH  5949.00
83  Lab A          BAP [ng/g]  HKH    38.71
332 Lab A         IPYR [ng/g]  MGT    26.53
36  Lab A         NSAR [ng/g]  HGT   566.64
680 Lab B           EC [ng/g]  SKH     0.00
2   Lab A         AFB1 [ng/g]  HGT     0.00
681 Lab B        HCHO [mug/g]  SKH     7.04
641 Lab A           EC [ng/g]  SKH     0.00
245 Lab A      CH3CHO [mug/g]  HPT 14045.95
132 Lab B       di-CHO [ng/g]  HKH 11360.00
846 Lab B         NH3 [mug/g]  SPT   952.00
551 Lab A          BAP [ng/g]  MPT    38.71
280 Lab B           Be [ng/g]  HPT    21.70
731 Lab A         NIC [mug/g]  SMH   720.00
225 Lab B         NMOR [ng/g]  HMH     0.00
604 Lab B           Hg [ng/g]  MPT    11.10
460 Lab B         NNC [mug/g]  MKH    22.00
222 Lab B         NH3 [mug/g]  HMH  1116.00
659 Lab A         NPYR [ng/g]  SKH   123.40
470 Lab A         AFB1 [ng/g]  MMH     0.00
523 Lab B           Dry.M (%)  MMH     6.40
52  Lab B           Cr [ng/g]  HGT 20438.00
701 Lab B           pH [unit]  SKH     1.04
538 Lab B         NNC [mug/g]  MMH     0.00
458 Lab B         NIC [mug/g]  MKH  5004.00
15  Lab A       di-CHO [ng/g]  HGT  3006.44
758 Lab B           EC [ng/g]  SMH     0.00
767 Lab B         NDMA [ng/g]  SMH   402.80
688 Lab B        NDELA [ng/g]  SKH     6.96
89  Lab A      CH3CHO [mug/g]  HKH  8052.61
694 Lab B         NNC [mug/g]  SKH    30.00
537 Lab B         NMOR [ng/g]  MMH     0.00
248 Lab A         DBAA [ng/g]  HPT     0.00
682 Lab B           Hg [ng/g]  SKH     0.50
683 Lab B         IPYR [ng/g]  SKH    30.83
167 Lab A      CH3CHO [mug/g]  HMH  7879.44
172 Lab A           Dry.M (%)  HMH    35.40
730 Lab A           Ni [ng/g]  SMH 12110.00
39  Lab A           Se [ng/g]  HGT   119.00

pvar2 <- ggplot(subset(labdata_snus_var), aes(x=Tobacco.Constituent, y=value)) +
geom_col(aes(fill = type), position = 'stack') +
facet_wrap(~Lab, nrow = 2) +
# ggplot(df) + geom_bar(aes(B, fill = C), position  = 'stack', width = 0.9) +
# facet_wrap(~A, nrow = 1) + theme(panel.spacing = unit(0, "lines"))
# geom_linerange(aes(ymin=Avg-StDev, ymax=Avg+StDev), position = position_dodge(width = 0.4),  width = 0.2, alpha = 0.4) +
# geom_point(aes(shape = type, stroke = 0.8), position = position_dodge(width = 0.4), size = 2, alpha = 0.7) +
# scale_shape_manual(name = "SLT Type", values = c(0, 1, 2, 3)) +
# scale_shape_manual(name = "SLT Type") +
#only 7 values withour snus
# # scale_shape_manual(name = "SLT Type", values=c(15,18,16,17,19)) +
# scale_color_manual(name = "SLT Type", values=c("#663300","#CC9900","#FF3399","#FF3300","#00CCCC","#6600CC","#CC6699", "#990033", "#999999", "#E69F00", "#56B4E9", "#009E73" )) + #only 7 values withour snus
# geom_text(aes(label= type), position = position_dodge(width = 0.5)) +
# facet_wrap(~Lab) +
# scale_y_sqrt(sec.axis = dup_axis()) +
# annotation_logticks(sides = "lr") +
theme_bw() +
# labs(color='type', size = 10) +
theme(axis.text.x = element_text(size = 8.5, angle = 45, hjust = 1, face="bold"),
axis.text.y = element_text(size=10, face="bold")) +
xlab("Chemical Constituent") + ylab("Variability with Maximum") 
pvar2
```

Without comments code is pasted below. What I need to do is have stacked columns besides each other for Lab A, Lab B ......and so on for the entire data:

```
pvar2 <- ggplot(subset(labdata_snus_var), aes(x=Tobacco.Constituent, y=value)) +
  geom_col(aes(fill = type), position = 'stack') +
  facet_wrap(~Lab, nrow = 2) +
  theme_bw() +
  # labs(color='type', size = 10) +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(size = 8.5, angle = 45, hjust = 1, face="bold"),
        axis.text.y = element_text(size=10, face="bold")) +
  xlab("Chemical Constituent") + ylab("Variability with Maximum") 
pvar2
```

Here is my output right now:
[image]

Comment: can you give a small set of data for a reproducible example and show how far you've gotten with `geom_bar` ?

Comment: For example, `d <- data.frame(x=c(0.5,0.5,0.3,0.7),expand.grid(f=c("a","b"),g=c("A","B"))); ggplot(d,aes(g,y=x,fill=f)) + geom_bar(stat="identity")` gets you the start. Then you probably need `facet_wrap()` or `facet_grid()` to make separate panels for every country, and then lots of fussing with styles and labels etc.. But it will help a lot if you can show what stage you've gotten to (and don't expect people to provide a complex solution from scratch ...)

Comment: @BenBolker please find sample data and some code above. I am using a facet wrap but that's not the same as the picture, is it? And I think there should be an easier work around for this in R gg

Comment: @https://stackoverflow.com/users/8449629/z-lin thanks for always helping out :)

Comment: so to be clear, you want stacked bars showing relative composition for each lab/constituent combination, with lab A next to lab B, then something like 30 panels arranged horizontally, one for each constituent?

Comment: @Ben Bolker; yes, exactly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a start:

```
labdata <- transform(labdata,
                     lab=gsub("Lab ","",lab),
                     constituent=trimws(constituent))

library(ggplot2)
library(colorspace)
theme_set(theme_bw()+theme(panel.spacing=grid::unit(0,"lines"),
                           legend.position="bottom"))
pvar2 <- ggplot(labdata, aes(x=lab, y=value)) +
    geom_col(aes(fill = type), position = 'fill') +
    facet_wrap(~constituent,nrow=1) +
    scale_fill_qualitative_discrete()
print(pvar2)
```

Some additional tweaks I would consider:

- fix x- and y-axis labels
- replace spaces in constituents with newlines (so units appear on a second line in the strip labels)
- remove constituents that are never >0
- arrange constituents and types in a sensible (non-alphabetical) order
- consider a different colour scheme

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks @Ben Bolker; I'll play around with this and keep you posted. Cheers

Comment: here is what I changed. I was thinking of pushing the units to the next line but it looks fine if I group my data in the plot. We are still expecting data for the zeros :) Thanks a lot.

Comment: I want to appreciate the help provided by all above users in this thread and the stackoverflow community for your assistance in visualization of data in one of my upcoming publications. Kindly contact me if you do not consent to using your user ID in the acknowledgements. Thank you and all the best! Stay safe and healthy!!